# Magnetic dipole in gradient magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, dipole

I know that a magnetic dipole in a uniform magnetic field will precess.

What happens qualitatively (or quantitatively) to a magnetic dipole in a gradient magnetic field? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment), "In a case when the external magnetic field is non-uniform, there will be a force, proportional to the magnetic field gradient, acting on the magnetic moment itself." I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Answer (score 1):

As the article explains, the force on a magnetic dipole in a non-uniform magnetic field is

$$\vec F=\vec\nabla(\vec m \cdot \vec B)= (\vec m\cdot\vec\nabla)\vec B.$$

The final expression involves the directional derivative of the magnetic field in the direction of the dipole moment. This is what  it means by “proportional to the magnetic field gradient”.

If you want, you can write this as $\vec m\cdot(\vec\nabla\vec B)$ where the parenthesized expression is a tensor which is indeed the gradient of the magnetic field. The gradient of a scalar field is a vector field; the gradient of a vector field is a (rank-2) tensor field.

Comment: In an uniform magnetic field $\vec B$, is the $\nabla\vec B$ always 0?

Comment: @LorisFoe Yes, the gradient of a uniform vector field is always 0 everywhere, so while a non-zero spatially-uniform magnetic field *does* exert *torque* on a dipole, it does *not* exert *force* on it.